# Inject a value to object properties at run time in c#

Tags: c#, code-injection

I have a class like this:

```
public class ChildForm extends System.Windows.Forms.Form{
   public int childId;
}
```

I call it like this:

```
Type baseType = Type.GetType("ChildForm");
System.Windows.Forms.Form formCall = (Form)System.Activator.CreateInstance(baseType);
//How can i set childId properties here?
```

The ChildForm could be many forms, that's why i need to use reflection and use the parent form to display it.But i don't know how to set the child properties. can this be done with properties injection?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just instantiate the form normally and just set its propery/field directly.  What are you gaining through using reflection?  If you don't know the type of form that is to be instantiated, you could make them all implement an IChildForm interface that has a property called ChildId. You'd then be able to instantiate the form and set its child id without reflection.  Setting values using reflection should generally be avoided unless no other option is available, as it's harder to inspect the code and determine what you'll break when changing stuff.

Comment: i know that can be done using ParentClass or interface. But i'm looking for another options, since the code is already too big to change. But i will keep it in mind when i rewrite everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is a [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx), not a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx). And to set its value you could do this:

```
var baseType = Type.GetType("ChildForm");
System.Windows.Forms.Form formCall = (ChildForm)System.Activator.CreateInstance(baseType);
baseType.GetField("childId").SetValue(formCall, 5);
```